# Generating charts from Google Forms data via Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-charts

I have two columns that are generated from a Google Forms:

[image: Google Sheets Table]

I would like to create two pie charts, one for City A and one for City B, showing the percentages of male and females from those cities. I am trying to get the count of:

- all males in City A,
- males in City B,
- females in City A, and
- females in City B

in order to create the pie charts. I can then save these values in a new sheet and generate the pie charts (or bar charts). So I thought I could use COUNTIFS as in Excel but that is not available. I have tried this formula:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER('Form Responses'! B2:B100, 'Form Responses'! B2:B100="Male", 'Form Responses'! C2:C100, "City B" ))
```

which didn't seem to get the right answer.

This formula seems to work:

```
=INDEX( SUMPRODUCT( ('Form Responses'! B2:B100 = "Male") * ('Form Responses'! C2:C100 ="City B") );1)
```

and I have been told that:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER('Form Responses'! B2:B100;('Form Responses'! B2:B100="Male")*('Form Responses'! C2:C100="City B")))
```

would also work.

Is that the best way to go about getting the information I need for the pie charts, or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Are there only two possible values for City, or can it be anything?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal For this example, lets assume there are only two cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the strings, so that the row `Male | City A` is represented as `MaleCity A`, and count the occurrences of those strings.

Given that column `B` contains either `Male` or `Female`, and column `C` contains either `City A` or `City B`, you could count males/females in each city:

- Number of males in City A: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(B2:B;C2:C)); "MaleCity A")`
- Number of females in City A: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(B2:B;C2:C)); "FemaleCity A")`
- Number of males in City B: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(B2:B;C2:C)); "MaleCity B")`
- Number of females in City B `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(B2:B;C2:C)); "FemaleCity B")`

The percentage of males/females in each city can then easily be calculated.

See the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdFB5TVF0MVVXdVBfX0xuYXFFZXNXWlE&usp=sharing) I set up.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. It works. As I see it, the same number of steps are required.

Comment: Good to hear! If you're happy with the answer, you could click _Accept_. Or wait a few days to see if other possibilities show up.

Comment: I will wait a few days and then accept. Thanks @Vidar!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning:

> So I thought I could use COUNTIFS as in Excel but that is not available.

But it *is* available. A pivot table might be more convenient (on the right) but a similar table can be constructed with:

```
=countifs($A:$A,E$1,$B:$B,$D2)
```

as shown in the middle (yellow labels):

[image]